# Base change of $H^n(\Gamma, \mathrm{Sym}^{k}(R^2))$ - A small step in Eichler-Shimura

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, homological-algebra, modular-forms, group-cohomology

I'm currently learning Eichler-Shimura mapping and found the note [by Gabor Wiese](https://math.uni.lu/%7Ewiese/notes/MFII.pdf) is quite helpful. Yet I have come up with a quite detailed question.

Let $R$ be a ring (all rings in this post are commutative with identity). Let $V_{k}(R) := R[X,Y]_{k} = \mathrm{Sym}^{k}(R^2)$, where $R[X,Y]_{k}$ is the abelian group of all homogeneous polynomials in two variables $X$ and $Y$ of degree $k$. (Defined on page 12 of the note linked above)

Let $\Gamma \leq \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ be a subgroup of finite index. We can define the action of $\Gamma$ on $V_{k}(R)$ as
$$
    \left( \begin{pmatrix}
    a & b \\ c & d
    \end{pmatrix} \cdot f \right) (X,Y) := f \left( (X,Y) \begin{pmatrix}
    a & b \\ c & d
    \end{pmatrix} \right) = f(aX+cY, bX+dY), 
    $$
for all $\begin{pmatrix}
    a & b \\ c & d
    \end{pmatrix} \in \Gamma$ and $f \in V_k(R).$

We can check that then $V_{k}(R)$ is a $\Gamma$-module, and hence we can consider the group cohomology $H^{\bullet}(\Gamma, V_{k}(R))$.

Now let $\phi: R \rightarrow S$ be a ring homomorphism (or in other words, $S$ is an $R$-algebra), then **my question is: does the following holds**?
$$
H^n(\Gamma, V_k(R)) \otimes_{R} S \cong H^n(\Gamma, V_k(S))   \quad \quad (\star_n).
$$

I have read quite a lot of notes on these things yet it seems that everyone takes this for granted (at least for $n=1$ case, i.e. $(\star_1)$)? *Does this hold for general $n$?* Yet I have tried on proving this but failed. Sorry for being stupid and I'm not quite familiar with the base change stuff here and hoping that this can be a start for me to get familiar with such things.

(It seems that some of such base change property is obvious and some of them are quite deep. Unfortunately, I cannot distinguish the two now. :( )

Any further references are welcome as well.

**Edit**: At least I hope that $(\star_{1})$ holds in the two following cases:

1. when "$R \rightarrow S$" is $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}$;
2. when "$R \rightarrow S$" is $\mathcal{O} \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$,
   where $E  | \mathbb{Q}_p$ is a finite extension and $\mathcal{O}$ is its ring of integers.

**Edit**: My motivation for this question comes from the *Page 3* of the note [Hecke algebra valued Galois representations for $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$](https://patrick-allen.github.io/teaching/notes/lecture2.pdf), where the above two cases are claimed.

Sorry for the edit and thank you all for noticing this post!

**EDIT** I have deleted my further edit on Kunneth spectral sequence and put it as an answer below.

And still, I'm wondering **if there are any solutions without knowing the knowledges on spectral sequence?**

Thank you all again for kind comments and sorry for being so lengthy and maybe talkative.

Comment: If I remember correctly, there is a spectral sequence converging to $H^n(\Gamma, V_k(S))$ with terms like $Tor_i(H^j(\Gamma, V_k(R)), S)$ (maybe some minus signs in the indexing somewhere). The map $(\star)_n$ is the edge map. Hence $(\star)_n$ is an isomorphism for all $n$ if S is flat over R, or if the cohomology groups of $V_k(R)$ are flat over R (which I think always happens if 6 is invertible in R).

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Thank you for your comments! Yet I'm not quite familiar with spectral sequence (merely know the definition and some direct consequences). Could you provide some reference on the spectral sequence you mentioned above? (Moreover, what do you mean by *"6 is invertible in $R$"*?)  Thank you again! :)

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Thank you so much! I have grasp the things on spectral sequence today and gained some quite tiny improvement on this question, which were added in the post. So I'm wondering whether my understanding is correct and how to carry on the arguments? Thank you! :)

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Thank you so much for your comments and hints again! Now I have filled up some details on your comments and posted as an answer. (Though I only managed to give the proof on $(\star_1)$.)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: There're something WRONG as Professor David Loeffler pointed out in the comment. I shall correct this these days! Sorry for that!**

Though it seems that few people are interested in this problem, I shall post an answer to show what I have got. What follows is mainly filling up the details in Professor David Loeffler's great comment.

The main tool is the Kunneth spectral sequence, as the following theorem provides:

> **Theorem**: *(Weibel's Intro. to homological algebra, Theorem 5.6.4)* Let $P$ be a bounded below complex of flat $R$-modules and $M$ an $R$-module. Then there is a boundedly converging right half-plane spectral sequence
> $$
> E_{pq}^2 = \mathrm{Tor}_p^R (H_q(P), M) \Rightarrow H_{p+q}(P \otimes_{R} M).
> $$

Turn this into a cohomological version, we have
$$
E^{pq}_2 = \mathrm{Tor}^p_R (H^q(P), M) \Rightarrow H^{p+q}(P \otimes_{R} M).
$$

Now put $M=S$ here, and $P$ the cochain complex $C^{\bullet}(\Gamma, V_{k}(R))$. Then the right hand side of "$\Rightarrow$" turns into $C^{\bullet}(\Gamma, V_{k}(R)) \otimes_{R} S$. So to use this spectral sequece, we need to check that
$$ C^{\bullet}(\Gamma, V_{k}(R)) \otimes_{R} S = C^{\bullet}(\Gamma, V_{k}(S)) .$$

It seems that this is indeed a routine check.

Hence, we obtain the spectral sequence
$$
E^{pq}_2 = \mathrm{Tor}^p_R (H^{q}(\Gamma, V_k(R)), S) \Rightarrow H^{p+q}(V_k(S)).
$$

Using the long exact sequence deduced from this (see Neukirch's *"Cohomology of number fields"*, Lemma 2.1.3), we have

$$
0 \rightarrow \mathrm{Tor}^1_R (H^{0}(\Gamma, V_k(R)), S)) \rightarrow H^1(\Gamma, V_k(S)) \rightarrow \mathrm{Tor}^0_R (H^{1}(\Gamma, V_k(R)), S) \rightarrow \mathrm{Tor}^2_R (H^{0}(\Gamma, V_k(R)), S) \rightarrow \cdots .
$$

Note that $\mathrm{Tor}^0_R (H^{1}(\Gamma, V_k), S)) = H^1(\Gamma, V_k(R)) \otimes_{R} S$, we obtain

$$
0 \rightarrow \mathrm{Tor}^1_R (H^{0}(\Gamma, V_k(R)), S) \rightarrow H^1(\Gamma, V_k(S)) \overset{(\star)_1} \rightarrow H^1(\Gamma, V_k(R)) \otimes_{R} S \rightarrow \mathrm{Tor}^2_R (H^{0}(\Gamma, V_k(R)), S) \rightarrow \cdots .
$$

Hence to make $(\star)_1$ an isomorphism, it suffices to require the vanishing of
$ \mathrm{Tor}^1_R (H^{0}(\Gamma, V_k(R)), S)$ and $\mathrm{Tor}^2_R (H^{0}(\Gamma, V_k(R)), S)$, which means we need at least one condition below holds:

1. $S$ is flat over $R$;
2. $H^{0}(\Gamma, V_k(R))$ is flat over $R$.

This is what Professor David Loeffler said in the comment.

However, I haven't found the way to solve for $(\star)_n$ in general, since the term "$\mathrm{Tor}_{R}^0$" only appears on the first terms of the induced long exact sequence. (Yet the $n=1$ case is enough to me up to now.)

As a new learner, I'm not quite sure that the above solution is correct. And I'm still hoping to get the general $n$ case, as well as a solution without the spectral sequence.

Thank you all for paying attention! Sincerely sorry for possible mistakes!

Comment: Something looks fishy here, there is a natural map from $H^1(\Gamma, V_k(R)) \otimes S)$ to $H^1(\Gamma, V_k(S))$ rather than the other way around. This is because there is indeed a minus sign in the indexing of the spectral sequence (as I suspected); it should be $Tor^R_{-i}(H^j(\Gamma, V_k(R)), S)$ as the $E_2^{ij}$ term.

Comment: Incidentally, if $\Gamma \subseteq \operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ has no torsion (which is true for most finite-index subgroups) then its cohomological dimension is 1, so $(\star)_n$ is only interesting for $n = 0$ and $n = 1$.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Thank you! The arrow of $(\star_1)$ I wrote is indeed quite strange. So it seems that I got the cohomology version of Kunneth spectral sequence wrong, and maybe I shall search for the correct version or go through the proof of it to see what's really going on? Yet I'm a bit confused on the "$\mathrm{Tor}$" with *negative* index. I wonder that could you provide any reference on this?

Comment: ...... I've always been wondering why many notes insist on requiring that the congruence subgroup $\Gamma \leq \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is torsion free, and your second comment really helps. Now it seems that I shall grasp something on the notion *cohomological dimension* to really understand what's going on here :)

Comment: There is indeed no such thing as negative Tor groups; but in order to get the arrows going the right way, you have to consider this as a *second* quadrant (cohomological) spectral sequence, i.e. the term $E^{ij}_r$ is only non-zero in the region $\{ (i, j): i \le 0, j \ge 0\}$. Compare e.g. Theorem 1.4(2) in this paper of Pottharst: https://msp.org/ant/2013/7-7/ant-v7-n7-p02-s.pdf

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Thank you! I will carefully learn that and correct the above stuff. :)